# PHP - "if statement" for multiple sets of conditions not working

Tags: php, xml, if-statement

Below is some simple and basic code for an internet user to shop for products using keywords. Here are the variables that retrieve the keyword values sent by the user, which are then used to parse the XML document below.

```
$Name  = $_GET["name_keywords"];
$Price = $_GET["price_keyword"];
$Store = $_GET["store_keywords"];
```

The internet user does NOT have to submit search queries and send value to all three variables - IE she/he can search by price only, or by name AND price etc). Therefore some of the variables may be NULL when used to parse XML document below. So my "if statement" below in the `foreach` loop has to take account for that.

The if statement below is the problem, as it does not work. Any advice on coding the if statement so it can parse the XML document for matching criteria on one, two OR three conditions and take into account that some variables might be null? Thanks!

```
<?php

    $xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
    foreach($xmlDoc->product as $Product) 
    {
        if (($Name == $Product->name) && (!empty($Price) && $Product->price == $Price) && ($Store) && $Product->store == $Store)) 
        {
            echo "Name: " . $Product->name . ", ";
            echo "Price: " . $Product->price . ", ";
            echo "Price: " . $Product->store . ", ";
        }
    }
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<products>
  <product type="Electronics">
    <name> Desktop</name>
    <price>499.99</price>
    <store>Best Buy</store>
  </product>

  <product type="Electronics">
    <name>Lap top</name>
    <price>599.99</price>
    <store>Best Buy</store>
  </product>

  <product type="Hardware">
    <name>Hand Saw</name>
    <price>99.99</price>
    <store>Lowes</store>
  </product>
</products>
```

Comment: You might need to cast the node as a string before using it in an `if` statement.

Comment: You have a brackets missing e.g.: && $Product->price == $Price) try:  && ($Product->price == $Price)

Answer (score 0):

you should check three conditions. in each condition you check two alternative posibilities:

- variable is empty
- variable is equal to product parameter.

so your condition should look like:

```
if (    (empty($Name) ||  $Product->name == $Name)
     && (empty($Price) || $Product->price == $Price)
     && (empty($Store) || $Product->store == $Store)
) {
```